# Sending a message to JGroup cluster from external resource

Tags: jgroups

I would like to send a message to the nodes in my JGroup cluster, not via one of the nodes, but from an external resource.

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

STOMP protocol allows STOMP clients to connect to any of the Jgroups cluster nodes. The STOMP implementation is available from Jgroups 2.11.0.Beta2.

Can find more details at  http://planet.jboss.org/post/stomp_for_jgroups

The STOMP client can be implemented in any language, can be started,  stopped any time without affecting the whole cluster nodes and can be a light weight process which just connects to the cluster nodes and communicate.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)